# Is it possible for std::function to contain multiple methods?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo {
    private:
        std::function<?> func;

    public:
        void call_func (?) {
            this->func(?);
        }

        void set_func (std::function<?> func) {
            this->func = func;
        }
};

class Bar {
    public:
        Bar () {
            Foo foo;
            foo.set_func(std::bind(&Bar::func, this, std::placeholders::_1));
            foo.call_func(1);

            foo.set_func(std::bind(&Bar::func2, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
            foo.call_func(1, 2);
        }

        void func (int number) {
            std::cout << number;
        }

        void func2 (int number, int number2) {
            std::cout << number << '\n';
            std::cout << number2;
        }
};

int main () {
    Bar bar;
    return 0;
}
```

I want one instance of std::function to contain multiple methods that have different arguments types.

But I don't know if it's possible and how to call that function.

What is your take on this problem? Thanks for reading.

Usually, I use like following method. Yes, it's quite different in essense. I just want to know if there is another way.

```
foo.set_func([this]() {
    this->func(1);
});
foo.call_func();

foo.set_func([this]() {
    this->func2(1, 2);
});
foo.call_func();
```

Comment: You could have an `std::variant<std::function<void(int)>, std::function<void(int, int)>>`. But I'll admit I have difficulty imagining the scenario where this would be useful though.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "contain". Are you saying that you want to use `some_foo.func` to call different functions at different times, even though the type signatures differ? Okay, so - what is your plan for providing the correct data each time you call it?

Comment: I think you are looking for a dynamically typed language, not C++.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Yes, you are right. I want to use Foo::func() to call different functions at different times.

Comment: Okay, and what *problem do you hope to solve* by having this flexibility?

Comment: Why just one `std::function` storing multiple functions instead of multiple `std::function` each storing a single function?

Comment: No, sorry, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: well, I have many classes like a Bar class, and they are using Foo class. Foo class is more universal class. for example, it is item of card that have responds to a user's click. and that click leads to a execution of a registered method. I'm sorry it's hard to explain clearly.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you do `foo.call_func(1)` when it holds `func2`?

Comment: How do you decide which parameters are needed? Technically you may use variadic templates. The question is when and how to instantiate.

Comment: @Raymond Chen If there was a way, I wanted to get a compilation error in that situation.

Comment: @Dmitry Kuzminov At first, I also thought about using Variadic Template. but I gave up because the problem got complicated as I modify a code. thank you guys for commentting.

Comment: @leftclick *"I'm sorry it's hard to explain clearly."* -- this is often a sign that you should spend more time thinking about your design. If you cannot explain your design clearly, you are at a disadvantage for coding your design cleanly.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, you are right. I agree with you. Thanks. Actually, the reason why I brought that up is because I'm not good at English. Usually, I ask questions with pieces of code without context. It's also my fault. :-(

Comment: @leftclick If you can explain clearly in your native tongue, then of course my comment does not apply. Maybe you can collaborate with someone on the translation? *For what it's worth: the English in this question does feel "stiff", but it's not bad.*

Comment: Maybe you want to create Interface with your several signature instead of `std::function`.

Comment: `if (time(NULL) % 2 == 1) foo.set_func(func1); else foo.set_func(func2); foo.call(1,2);` - The compiler would have to be able to predict the future (know what time the program is being run) in order to know whether to raise a compile-time error or not. Given your problem description, it seems that the code that does `foo.call()` is a click event. The click event's parameters are presumably fixed and not dependent upon who is registered for the click. Use those fixed parameters.